# Axios return a strange array in response to request

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, react-native, axios

I am trying to make a request on my database; I am using userid as an attribute to filter the response. The 'myid' used comes from my redux. When executing this request I have a somewhat strange array as an answer and I don't have the correct answer with the posts made by the user.

Request Response:

[image]

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation'
import Post from '../components/Posts/post'

const mapStateToProps =({user}) => {
  return {
    email:user.email,
    name:user.name,
    myid:user.id
  }
}

 class MyPosts extends Component {

  state={
    posts:[],
  }

  getPosts  = () =>{
    console.log(this.props.myid)
    axios.get(`/posts?userid=${this.props.myid}.json`)
      .then( res => {
        console.log(res)
        const rawPosts = res.data
        const posts =[]
          for (let key in rawPosts) {
            posts.push({
              ...rawPosts[key],
              id: key
            })
          }
          this.setState({ posts: posts})
        }
      )
      .catch (err => console.log(err))

  }
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.getPosts()
  }

  render () {


    return (
      <View style={styles.containerAll}>
        <NavigationEvents onDidFocus={() => this.getPosts()} />
        {console.log('Log do Return', this.state.posts)}
        <View>
          <Header style={{ backgroundColor: '#006bb3' }}>
            <Left>
              <Icon
                name="md-menu"
                type='Ionicons'
                style={{ color: "#FFF" }}
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()}
              />
            </Left>
            <Body>
              <Title>Meus anúncios</Title>
            </Body>
            <Right>

            </Right>
          </Header>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={{marginLeft:0, marginTop:15}}>
            <FlatList
              data={this.state.posts}
              keyExtractor={item =>`${item.id}`}
              renderItem={({item}) =>
              <TouchableOpacity 
                activeOpacity={0.7}
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Detail',{item :item})}>
                <Post key={item.id} {...item} />
              </TouchableOpacity>
              }
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps) (MyPosts)
```

I'm using:

- react-redux": 7.1.1,
- redux": 4.0.4,
- react": 16.8.6,
- react-native": 0.60.4",
- axios": 0.19.0,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a query with the filter without Firebase it is necessary to use some different parameters. I wasn't using these parameters, so I got this weird data in response. To perform a query correctly and need to modify the same. Thus we have:

```
axios.get(`/posts.json?orderBy="userid"&equalTo="${this.props.myid}"`)
```